# WPF converter to update in real time background colour of textbox on text change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

I have two textboxes for the firstname and second name of a user and I have created a converter to change the background colour of the textbox when the text equals a specific string.  The problem I am having is that the textbox will only update at run time and doesn't update when I change the text is the textbox.

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="forenameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" 
                 Background="{Binding Staff,Converter ={StaticResource StaffNameToBackgroundColourConverter1}}"  
                 Text="{Binding Staff.Forename, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
<Label  Content="Surname:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox x:Name="surnameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2"
                 Background="{Binding Staff,Converter={StaticResource StaffNameToBackgroundColourConverter1}}"  
                 Text="{Binding Staff.Surname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
```

Converter code:

```cs
public class StaffNameToBackgroundColourConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var staff  = (Staff) value;
        if (staff.Forename == "Donald" && staff.Surname == "Duck")
        {
            return "Yellow";
        }
        else
        {
            return "White";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Correct text input:

[image: Correct text input]

Wrong text input - no change:

[image: Wrong text input - no change]

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that `Staff` is not being notified of an update.  `Staff.Forename` and `Staff.Surname` are updating, but that does not automatically mean that `Staff` updates.  If you put a break point in your converter, I think you will see that it is never reached when you start typing in your textboxes.  Your converter is fine, the trouble is in the data to which your textboxes are bound.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your `Binding`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="forenameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" Background="{Binding Staff, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter ={StaticResource 
    StaffNameToBackgroundColourConverter1}}" Text="{Binding Staff.Forename, 
    Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>

<TextBox x:Name="surnameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
    Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" Background="{Binding Staff, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource 
    StaffNameToBackgroundColourConverter1}}" Text="{Binding Staff.Surname, Mode=TwoWay, 
    NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
```

This will update the binding source *as* the user types each letter. You can find out more from the [Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) page at MSDN.

Comment: I've tried using the UpdateSourceTrigger but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to tell you. This property does what you asked for... maybe you should try it on a simpler binding or read the linked page to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should return some brush object than colors to background like below

```
public class StaffNameToBackgroundColourConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo 
 culture)
{
    var staff = (Staff)value;
    if (staff.Forename == "Donald" && staff.Surname == "Duck")
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

    }
    else
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you added the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the wrong binding. You have to add it to the binding of the `Text` property.

Second, you bound the `Text` property to `Staff.Forename` but the `Background` to `Staff`. The `Background` property doesn't know that `Staff` has changed when you write in `Staff.Forename`. You have to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Staff` property when you write in the `Staff.Forename` property. Same for `Staff.Surname`.