# XAML TextBlock animate BackGround if new value exceeds previous

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, binding

TextBox is binded to property of type int in ViewModel. Its value continuously changes and notifies View. I want to animate its `Background`. If the new value exceeds the previous value, set `Background` to green for 1 sec, if not, set red.

How can I do it?

**UPDATE:**
This is the closest thing for now.  But color is always the same regardless the new value exceeds the previous one or not.

```
<Style x:Key="SuperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation From="Transparent" To="LightGreen" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <ColorAnimation From="LightGreen" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use converters ,Bind Textbox background to your value and pass it to concerter which returns color brush to your textbox

See link

[WPF converter to update in real time background colour of textbox on text change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768084/wpf-converter-to-update-in-real-time-background-colour-of-textbox-on-text-change)